# How to get index of selected value in Dropdown list javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

How to get index of selected value in Dropdown list in an event function. Here's my code.

```
function(data, event) {
    console.log(data);
    var k = self.selectedValue;
}
```

data has list of all values in DropDown list. But how to get index of it.

Comment: What is *data*, an array? options collection? How do you now which one is selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`this.value` forselected  value

`this.selectedIndex` for index

Comment: I want inside the function. The values you have given are undefined

Comment: A text property? I think you're confusing the [DOM select element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-select-element) with an [option element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-option-element).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var e = document.getElementById("controlID");
var strUservalue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var strUsertext = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement
Look for "selected Index".

```
// return the index of the selected option
alert(select.selectedIndex); //select is your element
```